# ArcMap 10.8 won't close properly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, schema-locks

Using Windows 10 Pro, ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.

I have been having a really, really bad time with ArcMap not shutting down properly. It wasn't always this way, but for the last year or so I've had to essentially have Task Manager open at all times as part of my everyday routine. It is not unusual for me to run 20 to 30 instances of ArcMap total throughout the day - not all at once, of course. It simply refuses to shut down properly. There are times when I literally save and close every map I have open, where even Task Manager is not displaying any lingering ArcMap processes, and I still have lock files that won't go away.

Is this a known issue? or does my experience sound extreme? We are a small shop of maybe 4 users total, we do not do anything in an Enterprise environment, and we all experience this issue to some degree, but I have it the worst. I just want to know if going to Esri with this is worth it.

Comment: That's not normal/expected behavior. Do you have an exotic filesystem solution or high-latency volume where data is stored? This sort of issue is better worked with Tech Support (due to the round-trip on things to try).

Comment: Also, since Tech Support will want to reproduce this with 10.8.1 (the terminal 10.8 release), you should try installing that first.

Comment: I feel your pain.  Orphaned file locks are a well-known ESRI "feature" that has existed for many years.  Google *esri orphaned locks* to see what I mean.  My solution was to move to QGIS for all my work, except for a few things that Arc Desktop was better at.  Still, whenever I do use Arc Desktop, I have to constantly close and restart sessions, which usually clears out the file locks.  However, there are still times when Arc won't close and I have to kill with Task Manager.  This "feature" has been around since early 10.x versions, maybe even 9.x, on different Windows versions and computers..

Comment: Are your four users working with the same MXD files inadvertently?  Do you have anyone running external Python scripts on the same workspaces that your MXDs use as their data sources?